# Proper DOM event for when an HTML template is to be made (with VueJS)

Tags: dom, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to run a METHOD when a template element is rendered but I'm not sure which DOM event to use:

```
<template v-on:something="method(parameter)">
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **mounted** (One of Vue's life cycle hooks):

```
mounted: function() {
  console.log("Your Vue application is mounted!");
}
```

Comment: I'm avoiding mounted because of the way my components are written :(

Comment: Using mounted isn't a bad practice. It can do the work.

Comment: way ahead of you!

Answer (score 0):

use updated()

```
 updated() 
    { 
      this.testing(parameter);
    },
    methods:{  
    testing:function(parameter){ 
        try {
            //code
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } 
    }
}
```

http://www.laraphp.com/initialize-js-functions-vue-jsmaterialize-modal-popup-auto-initialize/